# How do I speed drift in Trackmania Stadium and what do I use it for?

Tags: trackmania-2

How do I effectively speed drift in Trackmania<sup>2</sup> Stadium? I'm looking for this in terms of game mechanics and not what keys/buttons to press.

I'm also wondering *how* to use speed drifting. When turning a tight corner, is there an advantage or disadvantage to doing this instead of grip driving (not drifting) or letting off the gas? Assume time does not matter here.

Note: speed drifting is different from regular drifting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start a speed drift you will want to first build up a decent amount of speed. The faster you are going the longer you will be able to keep the drift going. Then you just sustain it by gently tapping the keyboard.

Other than that you will just need to practice it until you get good at it.

You can view a tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i8RAKrK8haI).

Speed Drifting is a good technique to learn because it gives a slight boost in speed. It's good for slight corners, not tight ones, where you have a high speed going into the corner.

If you have more detail as to what exactly you are looking for, please feel free to update your question.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I have updated my question with some more information.